Why are confidence intervals valid?
Recently, I began my statistics journey to understand the field better. Previously, my experience with statistics consisted of memorizing formulas, conditions, and applications of the latter. While one can often get away with such a superficial understanding, I overlooked the intuition behind most statistical practices.
In particular, I have begun to question the mathematical merit of confidence intervals. My theoretical understanding is as follows. Underlying any confidence interval is the notion of a sampling distribution, a theoretical distribution where we include the sample statistic for every possible sample of size n; the mean of this distribution is the true population parameter. From there, we select a desired confidence level (represented by a t or z value), and, using the standard deviation of our theoretical sampling distribution, we construct an interval. By definition, our confidence level will represent the percentage of total samples from our sample distribution that are within the margin of error of the true population statistic. In other words, if we were to repeatedly collect samples of size n and construct confidence intervals of the same confidence level, we would expect that $C%$% of these intervals would capture the true population parameter.
In theory, the math checks out. But, in practice, we do things that diverge from this theoretical underpinning. I will illustrate three cases where I have doubts:
Suppose, for instance, that we are attempting to create a confidence interval for a population proportion. The central limit theorem for proportions and mathematical reasoning leads us to conclude that the sampling distribution for a sample of sufficiently large size n is normally distributed with a mean of $p$ and a standard deviation of $\sqrt(\frac{p(1-p)}{n})$. In theory, if we were to take our $\hat{p}$ and create an interval using our desired confidence and the standard deviation outlined above, we would expect that $C%$% of these intervals would capture the true population parameter. But, we do not do this because we do not know what $p$ is and thus do not know the sampling distribution's standard deviation. Instead, we use $\hat{p}$ as a stand-in in the standard deviation equation: $\sqrt(\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n})$. Even though I know $\hat{p}$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$, how can we be sure that $C%$% of hypothetical intervals will capture the true population parameter?
Of course, I have the same doubts when it comes to estimating a population mean. The central limit theorem for proportions and mathematical reasoning leads us to conclude that the sampling distribution for a sample of sufficiently large size n is normally distributed with a mean of $\mu$ and a standard deviation of $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt(n)}$. In theory, if we were to take our $\bar{x}$ and create an interval using our desired confidence and the standard deviation outlined above, we would expect that $C%$% of these intervals would capture the true population parameter. But, we do not do this because we often do not know what $\sigma$ is and thus do not know the sampling distribution's standard deviation. In these cases, we use the standard error to approximate the standard deviation: $\frac{s_x}{\sqrt(n)}$. Given this change, how can we be sure that $C%$% of hypothetical intervals will capture the true population parameter?
For the more general case, where the central limit theorem may not apply, statisticians use bootstrapping to calculate a confidence interval. In summary, they create many, many samples with replacement of size n from their original sample of size n. By plotting the sample statistic of each of these samples, we can create a psuedo-sampling distribution. From there, we can create a confidence interval by selecting two percentiles that are equidistant from the 50th percentile. For instance, creating an interval with the values at the 5th and 95th percentiles represent a 90% confidence interval. Yet, this seems like a huge stretch. That is, we are assuming that the standard deviation of our psuedo-distribution is the standard deviation of our true sampling distribution. How can we be sure that $C%$% of hypothetical intervals will capture the true population parameter?

We can be sure that C% of hypothetical intervals will capture the true population parameter because our confidence strictly applies only within the statistical model  that yielded the interval. We extrapolate from that to the real world data generating system.
